# Calculate Field Get Sum

Tags: acumatica

Hi i'm having trouble finding the correct attribute syntax to calculate the total sum for an unbound field.

Could somebody point me into the right direction?

I have a custom DAC and a unbound field called Actual

Also in my DAC is employeeid, projectid and taskid.

I want Actual to show the sum of the quantities of all project transactions that contain employeeid, projectid etc. Pretty simple right?  I know theres a SumCalc but am not sure on how to use it.

Comment: I think you should look at T200 acumatica training Example 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no attribute in Acumatica to calculate total sum for an unbound field. The PXFormulaAttribute and the PXUnboundFormulaAttribute are designed to always store aggregated value inside a bound field.

To calculate total sum for an unbound field, you should implement FieldSelecting handler as shown in Step 11.8: Calculating the Total Amount of the T300 training course.

Comment: Yea I ended up calculating it and then assigning it to the field in the RowSelected event.   That works fine.

Comment: You must use FieldSelecting instead of the RowSelected event as RowSelected is invoked several times per roundtrip.